# How to combine two connected sockets into one conversation?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am doing kinda server. So two separate peers are connected to a server program - "ClientA - Server" and "ClientB - Server"

I want to connect them together - "ClietA - ClientB" directly, without receiving and dispatching data by the server, like ClienA and ClientB are just connected directly.. like a commutation system in a Phone station - connect them with "a wire" and let they talk to each other.

Is there such technique under .NET?

Comment: In general this is hard problem. Some technologies that you might look up to see how tricky this is include [ICE](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245), [STUN](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389), and [TURN](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5766). Most chat/messaging software for example uses a server to relay data between peers.

Comment: Thank you. will try byPass technique.